# How can I have a tkinter popup message with yes or no button and has a dialog box on the same popup message?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-text

I want to create a simple tkinter GUI that popes up a message with YES or NO buttons but also has a dialog box.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

messagebox.askyesno("test", "Did you enter your name?")
my_var = simpledialog.askstring(title="Test",prompt="enter sentences:")
print(myvar)

root=tk.TK()
```

I don't want to have two popups I want to have only one with a dialog box big enough to type three sentences and has a yes or no button. Is there a way to accomplish this in python3?

Comment: You will have to create your own window with the entries and buttons

Comment: Make a class that inherits from `Tk()`, and custom make that, just like how you would do on a normal window.

Comment: @CoolCloud well considering it would be a popup or so I understood wouldn't it be better to inherit from `Toplevel`? because then also not adding parent could be handled whereas it would be difficult to add more windows if inheriting from Tk and it is not meant as the main window.

Comment: @Matiiss `Tk` is better because using `Toplevel` on its own creates 2 windows. Also there are no disadvantages to using `Tk` that I can think of

Comment: @TheLizzard: `Toplevel` doesn't create two windows unless you haven't yet created a window. If you already have a root window, it will only create one.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you please share a simple example of what you thinking?

Comment: @user8607309 You have to create a class, or a function that makes this buttons and entry widget

Comment: `askstring()` has already `OK` and `Cancel` buttons, so what the purpose of `askyesno()` in your case?

Comment: @acw1668 that is the only way I can take user input with a popup menu and an input box.

Comment: What I mean that using `askstring()` is enough in your case.

Comment: @acw1668 askstring has no yes or no buttons. Also, the input field is super small to write several sentences.

Comment: Why would there be an input box and "yes"/"no" options? what could the user write that he has to press either "yes" or "no", could You give an example of how such input would look like?

Comment: An example of a simple used case is you want to capture the user feedback at a very specific place of the run, so you pop up a box of yes/no question and have an input box so he can type his/her observations. This is very simple in C# but my code is all python base. If you know away of doing this please share an example.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to build a custom dialog using `simpledialog.Dialog`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog

class MyDialog(Dialog):
    # override body() to build your input form
    def body(self, master):
        tk.Label(master, text="Enter sentences:", anchor="w").pack(fill="x")
        self.text = tk.Text(master, width=40, height=10)
        self.text.pack()
        # need to return the widget to have first focus
        return self.text

    # override buttonbox() to create your action buttons
    def buttonbox(self):
        box = tk.Frame(self)
        # note that self.ok() and self.cancel() are defined inside `Dialog` class
        tk.Button(box, text="Yes", width=10, command=self.ok, default=tk.ACTIVE)\
            .pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        tk.Button(box, text="No", width=10, command=self.cancel)\
            .pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        box.pack()

    # override apply() to return data you want
    def apply(self):
        self.result = self.text.get("1.0", "end-1c")

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dlg = MyDialog(root, title="Test")
print(dlg.result)
root.destroy()
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: You are using the main root window which defeats the purpose of a popup. I want the popup to appear while keeping the main window running. The popup is momentary so it appears takes the user input and disappear so the user can continue with the next task.

Comment: @user8607309 No, the dialog is not the main root window.  The main root window is hidden in my example.

Comment: perfect. Is there away to kill only the popup window and keep the main window up? root.destroy will kill everything on TK window.

Comment: You can just use the dialog part, i.e. `dlg = MyDialog(...)`, in your code.  You can do whatever you want on the root window.